# Right join with no main table needed (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table with several rows per id:

```
Emp_id  date_checkin  hours
01      2014-05-14     6
01      2014-05-13     6
02      etc.
```

I want to produce a list of last checkin with the number of emps who last checked in on that date.  Ex.

```
chk_date    
2014-05-14      25
2014-05-13      12
2014-05-11      5
```

etc.

I'm using a RIGHT JOIN to the table to get the last date for each emp.  It looks like:

```
RIGHT JOIN ( Select   e.emp_id max(e.checkin_date) as chk_date
                 from     empcheckin as e
                 group by chk_date) as T1
       on T1.chk_datee = q.chk_date
```

This (inner) query does get the last checkin date for each id.

The questions are, what do I query in the main query since I don't need anything from another table?  If I query for all the dates, I'm going through thousands of records getting dates that don't even matter.
Also, what do I `JOIN` ON?

Comment: Do you want a count of the number of check ins or the number of unique employees who checked in? (If Employee 1 checked in twice in 1 day, will that contribute 1 or 2 toward the count for that day?)

Comment: Great question Zee.  I just want 1 (the latest) per emp.  So, to answer the first question; unique employees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really think you need a JOIN, but just some GROUP BYs, like this:

```
SELECT t.last_date_chckin, COUNT(DISTINCT t.emp_id) AS CountEmp
FROM (
   SELECT emp_id, MAX(checkin_date) AS last_date_checkin
   FROM empcheckin
   GROUP BY emp_id
) AS t
GROUP BY t.last_date_chckin
```

Comment: This looks so simple!  I did have to modify this a bit.  I don't know if it is because I'm using MySql or what.  It was requiring that I add an alias to the "derived table".   So, I added "AS T1 and prefixed each column name by T1.  Thanks for the great answer and I think I learned something that will help in future queries.

Comment: You mean like the alias I just added? That is a bit strange... there is no ambiguity here without aliases... at least that I see. Glad to have been useful.